# Powershell WMF5 Slow to call ps1

Tags: performance, powershell

Noticed dot sourced files were loading slowly in WMF5 on Windows 7.
This issue does not happen with WMF4.

- Created `test.ps1` with the content `"hello"`.
- Calling `.\test.ps1` takes anywhere from 2-8 seconds to call this file.

  ```
  Measure-Command { .\test.ps1 }

  Days              : 0
  Hours             : 0
  Minutes           : 0
  Seconds           : 2
  Milliseconds      : 397
  Ticks             : 23979752
  TotalDays         : 2.77543425925926E-05
  TotalHours        : 0.000666104222222222
  TotalMinutes      : 0.0399662533333333
  TotalSeconds      : 2.3979752
  TotalMilliseconds : 2397.9752
  ```

Here is my `$PSVersionTable`

```
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
    BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
    WSManStackVersion              3.0
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Re-install WMF5
- Run Powershell as Admin, x86, x64, -noprofile, -noninteractive
- Restart PC
- Test on other PCs on the Network

  - WMF4 PCs loaded the file instantly
  - WMF5 PCs all had performance issues
- Traced the performance with procmon, windows event log (nothing stood out)

After uninstalling WMF5, the command runs instantly. I'm not sure how to further track what is causing this performance issue. I have noticed McAfee shows the WMI service as (would be blocked) if the rule was active when running the command on WMF4 or WMF5. This may be an issue caused from antivirus.

Comment: Don't have a system to test on atm. but if you can reproduce an issue on different machines (and different scripts), submit it as a bug on Uservoice, https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell

Comment: Tested and no issue with Windows 7 and WMF5 (same version as yours). I guess McAfee's a good suspect.